# Ostream << and operator -= for classes?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have 2 classes `S` and `M`. When I try to use

```
cout << s3 -= m2;
```

I get an error that sates:

> no operator "-=" matches these operands  operand types are: std::ostream -=

```
class S
{ 
public:
    S& operator-=(M& m)
    {
        //my code
        return *this;
    }
}
```

I tried with 3 parameters, including `ostream`, but `-=` has only 2.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  `<<` has a higher precedence than `-=` so

```
cout<<s3-=m2;
```

is treated as

```
(cout << s3) -= m2;
```

and not

```
cout << (s3 -= m2);
```

You need to use the above form to get what you want.

Comment: I was thinking there may be a way without cast. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to fix this. The operator precedence rules in `c++` are fixed and cannot be overloaded.

The only possible solution is to change the using code. For example, if you write

```
cout << (s3 -= m2);
```

then your original code should work. Another option is splitting the line in two:

```
s3 -= m2;
cout << s3;
```